# Need help understand VB conditional logic and find equivalent in java

Tags: java, vb.net

I have a legacy project in Visual basic that needs to be converted to java.

I cant understand the following line...

```
If lastSendToggle And 128 Then
```

... where lastSendToggle is a byte and 128 is an int. What is the equivalent in java for this?

I tried...

```
if((lastSendToggle & 128) == 1 )
```

... but this doesn't work because statement is always false.

Comment: Try `!= 0` instead... and make sure you understand why a bitwise operation using `& 128` *could* never result in 1...

Comment: @JonSkeet TY. Your approach seems to work in my code but i can't understand why a bitwise operation using `& 128` never could result in 1. According to this "op1 & op2 -- The AND operator compares two bits and generates a result of 1 if both bits are 1; otherwise, it returns 0."  it should work, since 128 should be 1 and my other value (0 or 1) also should be able to produce a 1. I never worked with bitwise operators before so I'm probably missing something essential, can you point me in correct direction?

Comment: That's an accurate description for *two bits*, but you're performing that across multiple bits, because a byte is 8 bits. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_bitwise_operators.htm for example, or a good introductory book on C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet Once again, a big thank you! Your link made it perfectly clear and there where a big "aaaah" in my office seconds ago. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operation `x & 128` will *never* result in 1 for any value of `x`, because it's a bitwise operation. It will always either be 128 or 0, depending on whether that bit is set in `x` or not. (Note that 128 decimal = 10000000 binary, so there's only one bit that *can* be set in the result.)

So you could write this as:

```
if ((lastSendToggle & 128) == 128)
```

or

```
if ((lastSendToggle & 128) != 0)
```

Comment: In C or C++, you could omit the `!= 0` from the `if` and have equivalent code to the original VB.  Can you not do this in Java?

Comment: @Craig: No, because an `if` condition needs to be a `boolean`. This is a Very Good Thing IMO.